# React: passing JSX as a function argument

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to pass JSX code to define a new custom prop. For example

```
createChildComponent(ComponentTag, prop_definitions) {
    return <ComponentTag prop_definitions />
```

}

```
<button onClick={this.createChildComponent(Child1, { color: 'blue', handleClick = this.handleClick }}>Create</button>
```

Key/value and  variable assignments in the object did not work. Is there a way to pass JSX (in this case prop assignments) using arguments?

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by "did not work"? Specifically, what are you _trying_ to achieve here?

Comment: If you simply want for `ComponentTag` to be able to consume `prop_definitions`, see https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#spread-attributes

Comment: If you goal is to actually render `ComponentTag`, then believe you will need an entirely different approach

Comment: What you're doing doesn't really make sense. `onClick` should be a function, but you're passing it a JSX element. As Hamms said, if you're wanting to render `Child1` instead of the `<button/>` then your approach needs a complete change

Answer (score 0):

To pass props all you have to do is use the spread syntax.

```
createChildComponent(ComponentTag, props = {}) {
  return <ComponentTag { ...props } />
}
```

This'll spread your prop object out into key/value pairs as though you're passing the props explicitly.

Bonus points - set a default value of `{}` to `props` so that your method doesn't fall over if you omit the `props` parameter.

Comment: I believe you need curly braces around the spread, `{...props}`

Comment: "set a default value of `{}` to `props` so that your method doesn't fall over if you omit the `props` parameter"

Will it? From what I can tell spreading an undefined variable is harmless.

Comment: Ah, looks like react takes care of that for you.  Attempting to spread on undefined outside the context of react will yield `Cannot convert undefined or null to object`